# How to distinguish between NULL and NOT NULL during comparison

Tags: sql, compare, isnull

I have a situation, where I get a result set and based on the values from the result set I need to delete records, from another table.

Example :

```
ResultSet rs = SELECT col FROM TableA;
```

Now I dont know whether `rs.getString(1)` is `null` or not.

so if it is null i have to do :

```
DELETE FROM TableB WHERE col2 IS NULL;
```

if not null then :

```
DELETE FROM TableB WHERE col2 = rs.getString(1);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer using plain SQL or any sort of programming language?

Comment: I'd be using stored procedure to get the job done.
Also, I have more than one column with situation explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the normal comparison operator, it always returns false if one of the operands is null.

So you have to explicitly check for null values:

```
DELETE FROM TableB 
WHERE 
  col2 = rs.getString(1) OR -- Neither are NULL and they have the same value.
  (col2 IS NULL AND rs.getString(1) IS NULL) -- or Both are null.
```

Comment: But I have a problem, lets say Im having more than one column
and the same condition is applicable for all of them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM TableB 
WHERE ISNULL(col2,'VALUEISNULL') = ISNULL(rs.getString(1),'VALUEISNULL')
```

'VALUEISNULL' may be whatever you want that would not be a valid value for that field.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, a comparison between a `null value` and any other value (including another null) a using a logical operator `(eg =, !=, <, etc)` will result in a null, which is considered as false for the purposes of a where clause. The reasoning is that a null means "unknown", so the result of any comparison to a null is also "unknown". So you'll get no hit on rows using `my_column = null`.

SQL provides the special syntax for testing if a column is `null`, via is `null` and is `not null`, which is a special condition to test for a null (or not a null).